# PHP & Javascript: Unsecure?

Tags: php, javascript, security

Is it unsecure to embed PHP code in a javascript function?
My friend told me not to do it.

My script just inserts a number in the database if the message has been clicked (read).

```
<!--Insert into database when click-->
<script>
    function insert()
    { 
        <?php
        include 'db_connect.php';
        $usermsg = $_SESSION['username'];
        $message_id = $_GET['messageid'];
        mysql_query("UPDATE messages SET message_read='1' WHERE id='$message_id' AND to_user='$usermsg'");
        ?> 
    }
</script>
```

Should i do this any otherway? Or drop including php & mysql in my script and start over?

Comment: Um ... that won't do anything.

Comment: Why didn't you try if it worked? As Mimisbunnr said, it won't do anything.

Comment: I know the code wont do anything yet, but is it secure to do PHP & Mysql inside a javascript function?

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball: It's completely meaningless. PHP & MySQL can never be "inside" a Javascript function.

Comment: This makes no sense. Javascript runs on the browser. PHP runs on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try that code, it won't even work that way. You cannot embed server side code in javascript function.

What you want is to make a sepearate request that will handle the request. This method is called AJAX. With jQuery library you can make [AJAX POST request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) like this:

```
<script>
    function insert()
    { 
       //Example: Request the test.php page and send some additional data along (while still ignoring the return results).
       $.post("test.php", { messageid: "1" } );
    }
</script>
```

In test.php:

```
<?php 

  //Get Post Variables. The name is the same as 
  //what was in the object that was sent in the jQuery

  if (isset($_POST['messageid'])) {
      include 'db_connect.php';
      $usermsg = $_SESSION['username'];
      $message_id = $_POST['messageid'];
      mysql_query("UPDATE messages SET message_read='1' WHERE id='$message_id' AND to_user='$usermsg'");
  }

?>
```

Read the [Beginners Guide to Using AJAX with jQuery](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/)

And don't forget to [use parametrized sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php) to prevent sql injection attacks as this code in its current state is vulnurable.

Comment: Need to add validation/verification into this - ie. check `$usermsg` and `$message_id` to make sure that they are reasonable values.

Answer (score 10):

Your friend probably told you not to do it because it makes no sense whatsoever.

PHP is a preprocessing language whose parser runs on the webserver. The result of running PHP is the HTML/Javascript that your browser sees. Your PHP does not output anything (merely silently performing the SQL query whilst your HTML/Javascript page is being generated), so the Javascript that your browser sees is:

```
<script>
    function insert()
    { 
    }
</script>
```

PHP cannot be "inside" a Javascript function at all. There is no such concept.

Instead, consider an HTML `form`, or read up about "AJAX" when you're slightly more familiar with the web technologies heirarchy.

Answer (score 2):

It's insecure in that it's entirely possible for PHP to insert some text into the page that breaks the javascript. e.g.

```
<?php
    $name = "O'Brien";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var name = <?php echo $name ?>;
</script>
```

This would produce:

```
   var name = O'Brien;
```

which is illegal JS syntax. You're assigning an undefined variable `O`, which is immediately followed by an unterminated string literal `'Brien`. Surrounding this with quotes in the PHP page accomplishes nothing either:

```
  var name = '<?php echo $name ?>';
             ^                   ^-- added quotes
```

which now gives

```
  var name = 'O'Brien';
```

Now you've got a slightly different problem: Assigning a perfectly valid string literal `'O'`, followed immediately by an undefined variable `Brien`, followed by an unterminated string literal `';`.

The proper way to have PHP output text into a JS code block safely is to use json_encode:

```
 var name = <?php echo json_encode($name) ?>;
```

which produces:

```
 var name = "O'Brien";
```

and off you go.

Answer (score 1):

PHP/MySql runs on the web server. Javascript runs on the browser.

You should also think that anything that comes from the browser may be faked - therefore should validate/verify it. Javascript just makes the users experience more interactive as it does not require communication across the network. Use AJAX or forms to do the comms.